# Access Qwidget behind the QLabel for track moving

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm working on a qt widget project
I make it frameless and create my own custom frame for it
for drag window I subclass QWidget and use some event to keep track of window movement
everything is OK except one thing, as you can see I have a QLabel in my widget
this label are in the way of area of top_bar widget itself (because its in it actually.), So drag won't work because its on the way...
[image]
I don't know how can I fix it and keep the label
I know this is possible because [this project](https://github.com/Jorgen-VikingGod/Qt-Frameless-Window-DarkStyle) using the same way for keep track of QWidget, and its have a label in it too but work just fine
[image]

Comment: maybe this happens because of the frameless flag , remove it and test it again . I can't tell you what makes it exactly , Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I need to use frameless flags, because my window should be frameless, and also the project that I mention in the question used frameless flags too, I think its have something to do with the way I created the widget in designer... and about minimal reproducible, tbh I don't know what can I add to this question

Comment: I cant understand your meaning about `drag won't work ` .

Comment: @Parisa.H.R as I said I removed window border from my program, after that I need another way for drag and move window (because if I remove window border there is no way to move window any more like we do in normal program), so I subclass QWidget and inside that I added some event watcher (`mouseMoveEvent`, `mousePressEvent` and...) so based of them I can detect window movement and move window manually. until now everything is ok and I can move window by grab the widget. but if I add anything inside that widget (like a QLabel) its Prevent me from grab the widget again, so I cant move it anymore

Comment: thanks, now I understand your meaning .